# How to fill Array on second Activity with elements of EdiText of first Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two Activities the first is simple Activity but the second is ListActivity.I have EditText element and a button on the first activity,I want when I type smth. in edittext and click the button,I want to go to the second activity where the information I typed would be as list item,and so on.How to send data from editText to second activity so I could use setOnKeyListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check out the documentation on Intent, specifically Intent.putExtra():

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

This is used to pass aditional data with the intent. In your first activity, you'd put your data as extra into the intent, and in the second activity you'd rerieve that data and do whatever you need to do with it.